Fit longer table horizontally within textwidth
I'm currently working on finishing the text for my first paper. I have also displayed computational results in a table in the \sidewaystable environment. But now my supervisor has said he wants it as a horizontal table. But since it has many columns, it naturally goes over the edge. How can I work around this problem?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acro}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \begin{table}
        \footnotesize
        \caption{Computational results.} 
        \label{tab:initial_res}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
                \toprule 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-13} 
                Instance & LB & UB & Gap$^{1}$ & Time  & LB & UB & Gap & Time& \# Iterations & Time RMP  & Time SP & Time IP  \\
                \midrule
                1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
                2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
                3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
                4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \footnotesize
                \item $^1$ MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}


You are wasting a lot of space on the titles.  The easy solution is to use multiline titles with \multicolumn{1}{p{??}}{...} and possibly manual hyphenation.  Abreviations or roatetd titles are also possible.  You may need to reduce \tabcolsep as well.

Since you're employing the threeparttable package, I recommend you replace Gap$^{1}$ with Gap\tnote{1} and replace \item $^1$ with \item[1].

The 8 columns under "Bender's Decomposition" would appear to consist of a first group 4 columns that are organized the same way as are the 4 columns under "Compact Model", and a second group of 4 columns that are organized quite differently. Question: Might it make sense to label these two groups of 4 columns individually?

“Only the teletubbies can put an elephant into a handbag.”
So, if exactly this table should be a horizontal one, you can either use the left and right margin, e.g.:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed for a long time.
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{caption}% because of using table headings

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \begin{table}
        \footnotesize
        \caption{Computational results.} 
        \label{tab:initial_res}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \centerline{\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
                \toprule 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-13} 
                Instance & LB & UB & Gap$^{1}$ & Time  & LB & UB & Gap & Time& \# Iterations & Time RMP  & Time SP & Time IP  \\
                \midrule
                1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
                2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
                3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
                4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \footnotesize
                \item $^1$ MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}


or
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{caption}% because of using table headings
\usepackage{scrextend}% provides addmargin

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \begin{table}
      \begin{addmargin}{-\dimeval{\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}}
        \footnotesize
        \caption{Computational results.} 
        \label{tab:initial_res}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
                \toprule 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-13} 
                Instance & LB & UB & Gap$^{1}$ & Time  & LB & UB & Gap & Time& \# Iterations & Time RMP  & Time SP & Time IP  \\
                \midrule
                1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
                2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
                3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
                4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \footnotesize
                \item $^1$ MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.
            \end{tablenotes}
          \end{threeparttable}
          \end{addmargin}
    \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}


or make it much smaller and use only the right margin:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{caption}% because of using table headings

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \begin{table}
        \tiny
        \caption{Computational results.} 
        \label{tab:initial_res}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
                \toprule 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-13} 
                Instance & LB & UB & Gap$^{1}$ & Time  & LB & UB & Gap & Time& \# Iterations & Time RMP  & Time SP & Time IP  \\
                \midrule
                1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
                2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
                3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
                4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \footnotesize
                \item $^1$ MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}


But note, that this is almost unreadable.
Or use a larger paper format:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Computational results.} 
        \label{tab:initial_res}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
                \toprule 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-13} 
                Instance & LB & UB & Gap$^{1}$ & Time  & LB & UB & Gap & Time& \# Iterations & Time RMP  & Time SP & Time IP  \\
                \midrule
                1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
                2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
                3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
                4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \footnotesize
                \item $^1$ MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}


or smaller margins:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \begin{table}
      \footnotesize
        \caption{Computational results.} 
        \label{tab:initial_res}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
                \toprule 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-13} 
                Instance & LB & UB & Gap$^{1}$ & Time  & LB & UB & Gap & Time& \# Iterations & Time RMP  & Time SP & Time IP  \\
                \midrule
                1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
                2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
                3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
                4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \footnotesize
                \item $^1$ MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}


Another non-TeX but stylistic suggestion would be to split it into several tables, e.g., two for Compact Model and Benders Decomposition, or to reduce the table deleting some columns. I would try to split it into two tables (using package subcaption) and decrease the column distance of the second table a little bit:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \begin{table}
      \footnotesize
        \caption{Computational results.} 
        \label{tab:initial_res}
        \begin{subcaptionblock}{\textwidth}
          \centering
          \caption{Compact Model}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
                \toprule 
                Instance & LB & UB & Gap$^{1}$ & Time \\
                \midrule
                1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 \\
                2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 \\
                3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 \\
                4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item $^1$ MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
      \end{subcaptionblock}

      \bigskip
      
      \begin{subcaptionblock}{\textwidth}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.75\tabcolsep}
        \centering
        \caption{Benders Decomposition}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}
                \toprule 
                Instance & LB & UB & Gap & Time& \# Iterations & Time RMP  & Time SP & Time IP  \\
                \midrule
                1 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
                2 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
                3 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
                4 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
      \end{subcaptionblock}
    \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}


But with some reduction of the column headings and the column separation space, it would even fit as a single table:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{caption}% because of using table headings

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \begin{table}
      \newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
      \footnotesize
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.6\tabcolsep}
        \caption{Computational results.} 
        \label{tab:initial_res}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{l*6{S[table-format=2.2]}S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=1.2]}
                \toprule 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
                \cmidrule(l){2-5}\cmidrule(l){6-13} 
                \thead{Instance} & \thead{LB} & \thead{UB} &
                                                             \thead{Gap\tnote{1}} & \thead{Time\tnote{2}}  & \thead{LB} & \thead{UB} & \thead{Gap} & \thead{Time\tnote{2}} & \thead{\#\tnote{3}} & \thead{RMP\tnote{2}}  & \thead{SP\tnote{2}} & \thead{IP\tnote{2}} \\
                \midrule
                1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
                2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
                3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
                4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent
              and the current best lower bound.
            \item[2] Number of iterations.
            \item[3] These are duration times in seconds.% Or \unit{\milli\second}?
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}



I'd like to suggest that you employ a tabular* environment, set its target width to \textwidth, and provide a bit more structure to the header material. Using the machinery of the threeparttable package properly -- e.g., using \tnote directives -- would also be a good idea.

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{siunitx}  % not needed in this example
%\usepackage{acro}     % ditto

%% new:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[1][1-4]
    
\begin{table}[t]
\small % 10% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX determine intercolumn gaps

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Computational results.} 
\label{tab:initial_res}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{12}{c} }
\toprule 
  Instance
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} 
  & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
  \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-13} 
  & LB & UB & Gap\tnote{1} & 
  Time & LB & UB & Gap & 
  Time & \#\tnote{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Time} \\
  \cmidrule{11-13}
  &&&&&&&&&& RMP & SP & IP  \\
\midrule
  1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
  2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
  3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
  4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
        
\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.
\item[2] Number of iterations.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
    
\end{document}


I'd go with Mico's strategy, but with some changes.
The table fits with \small size and you don't need threeparttable because you know what the width of the table is.
It makes little difference, in the particular case, to use S columns, but it would if one of the figures had less digits in the integral part.
Note also that the placement of captions is at the bottom, in the standard classes. If you want them at the top, load caption.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htp]

\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local setting

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]}
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
}
\toprule 
Instance & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compact Model} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Benders Decomposition}\\
\cmidrule{2-5}\cmidrule{6-13} 
& {LB} & {UB} & {Gap\textsuperscript{1}} & {Time} & {LB} & {UB} & {Gap} & {Time} & 
\#\textsuperscript{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Time} \\
\cmidrule{11-13}
\multicolumn{10}{c}{} & RMP  & SP & IP  \\
\midrule
1 & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
2 & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
3 & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
4 & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\footnotesize
  \textsuperscript{1} MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and 
  the current best lower bound.

  \textsuperscript{2} Number of iterations
\end{minipage}

\caption{Computational results.} 
\label{tab:initial_res}

\end{table}

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}



Another option, with use of the talltblr of tabularray package, narower columns separations and longer column headers split into two rows. Consequently, table width is equal to \textwidth and font size used in table is \small:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{caption}% because of using table headings

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Computational results.}, 
  label = {tab:initial_res},
note{a} = {Inst.: Instance.},
note{b} = {MIP-Gap: Relative difference between the incumbent and the current best lower bound.},
note{c} = {Num. Iter.: Number of Iterations}
                    ]{colsep  = 3pt,
                      colspec = {@{} X[c] *{12}{Q[c,m]} @{}},
                      cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
                      cell{1}{2} = {c=4}{},
                      cell{1}{6} = {c=8}{}
                      }
    \toprule 
Inst.\TblrNote{a}
    &   Compact Model
        &   &   &   &   Benders Decomposition
                        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-13} 
    & LB & UB & Gap\TblrNote{b}   
                    & Time 
    & LB & UB & Gap & Time 
    & { Num.\\ Iter.\TblrNote{c}}  
                    & {Time\\ RMP}
    & {Time\\ SP}   & {Time\\ IP}  \\
    \midrule
1   & 42.21 & 45.47 & 11.10 & 72.00 & 44.77 & 44.88 & 0.23 & 33.62 & 12 & 2.86 & 33.08 & 0.84\\
2   & 41.14 & 46.88 & 12.24 & 72.00 & 45.82 & 45.88 & 0.14 & 18.65 & 89 & 2.12 & 18.30 & 0.17\\
3   & 38.73 & 43.77 & 11.52 & 72.00 & 43.34 & 43.37 & 0.08 & 14.63 & 84 & 2.34 & 14.24 & 0.07\\
4   & 86.84 & 37.10 & 16.26 & 72.00 & 95.73 & 95.80 & 0.07 & 23.45 & 88 & 2.31 & 22.92 & 1.54\\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}


